# Spring Boot @RequestBody parses only 0/null values?

Tags: java, spring, curl, spring-boot

I have a POJO "Problem" object:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Problem {
    int capacity;
    int weights[];
    int values[];
}
```

Which I am trying to parse in a Rest controller in Spring Boot:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public SolutionResponse calculateSolution(@RequestBody Problem problem) {
// problem = Problem(capacity=0, weights=null, values=null) ??
// Goes on ..
}
```

I am posting the following with cURL:

```
curl -d '{"problem": {"capacity": 60, "weights": [5, 2, 22], "values": [2, 5, 30]}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8088/endpoint/calculate
```

Looking into debug mode, it is indeed parsed, but as:

```
problem = Problem(capacity=0, weights=null, values=null)
```

So, it's wrong as they should have the values that I posted.

What could be the issue?

Comment: just pass this `{"capacity": 60, "weights": [5, 2, 22], "values": [2, 5, 30]}` from curl

Comment: .. I'm an idiot. Thank you. Feel free to answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json you are sending from curl is not correct.
It should be

```
{"capacity": 60, "weights": [5, 2, 22], "values": [2, 5, 30]}
```